# Startup up Scene samsung TV app

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I have create an Samsung TV App, for that I have created two scenes: Initial Scene and MainScene

So when the user launches my application I want that my InitialScene shows for 1 to second, then MainScene should show.

How to achieve that?

Comment: is this about Android or iOS?

Comment: Hi, you can try something like this... setTimeout(goToMainScene, 1000); Of course it depends how did you implement.

Comment: i tried that, in that case it jumps to mainscene directly and image on screen one is not displayed

Answer (score 0):

you should set a timer, after that try to change the focus on the MainScene just like this:
`

```js
MainScene.load();
MainScene.show();
MainScene.focus();
InitialScene.unload();
```

`
hope this will help